# On OSX Lion XCode shuts down the MacBook

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, shutdown

I have latest OSX Lion with XCode 4.1 on Macbook Pro. As soon as I type some code in XCode, my Screen shuts off and only option I have is to hard reboot my laptop. I have tried software updates to ensure everything is latest. How can I know who is causing this trip and shutoff of the screen and what are my options to fix it?

Comment: I have the exactly same issue with my MBP middle 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Console, maybe something is logged to the syslog that will indicate what is causing the shutdown.

Can you use the Macbook longer without running Xcode? Or your machine only shuts down when running Xcode?

Comment: It consistently shuts down only when I start using XCode for developing my application. I see something like this in console:9/8/11 7:33:54.238 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.ReportCrash) Falling back to default Mach exception handler. Could not find: com.apple.ReportCrash.Self

Comment: There is a thread on the Apple Forums about this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2152319?start=0&tstart=0